# .Net console app impersonate all domain users

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to write some code - just a console app - that will have access to all users' drive files.

With Document List v3 this is easy - just replace the list query's "default" with the user name, and you're away (using client login and admin credentials).

What is the Drive api's way of doing this? How do I retrieve a particular user's files?

There's a java version of this question (I think), but I can't find anything matching in the .Net api [OAuth Google API for Java unable to impersonate user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11660666/oauth-google-api-for-java-unable-to-impersonate-user)

Comment: I am trying to figure this out too.  I can get a auth code but when I put it into the example I run into an issue.